# How to add ( or attach ) variable on variable in JS

Tags: javascript, escaping

i stuck to attach counter-var (b) on text-variable (string) - not mathematical - Just to add counter(b) on data-var in JS...

**Example:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">    

<?php 
$i=0;
foreach ($sqldata as $data){
echo 'var data'.$i.' = 
Array("'.implode('", "', array_map('addslashes', $data)).'");';     
$i++;
}
echo 'var data_ges = '.$i.' ;';
?>

for (b=0; b<data_ges; b++){
document.writeln (data+b[1]); // ERROR LINE - How do i escape here ?
}

</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: That there include the dreaded *PHP code*. Confusing, *no*?

Answer (score 1):

You should just use array instead of trying to dynamically use a variable name :

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
  var data = [];
<?php 
$i=0;
foreach ($sqldata as $data){
echo 'data['.$i.'] = 
Array("'.implode('", "', array_map('addslashes', $data)).'");';     
$i++;
}
?>

for (b=0, l = data.length; b<l; b++){
document.writeln (data[b]); // ERROR LINE - How do i escape here ?
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the json_encode function to create a javascript-object where you can easily iterate over.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

Your php is making a set of variables like `data0`, `data1`. One way to capture these back is to grab them off the `this` or global `window` object:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data_ges; ++i) {
  document.writeln(window['data' + i]);
}
```

It would probably be better to actually make an array called `data` in the php though:

```
var data = [];
<?php 
foreach ($sqldata as $data) {
    echo 'data.push(' … ');';
}    
?>

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  document.writeln(data[i]);
}
```